# Laser Dry Electrostatic vs Indirect Electrostatic photographic

Tags: printer

My office is buying photocopy machine and we are stuck between the printing technology which is making it difficult to choose one.

[canon imagerunner 2520](http://www.canon.co.in/business/products/multi-function-devices/imagerunner/imagerunner-2520?languageCode=EN) has `Laser Dry Electrostatic Transfer System`

[Toshiba Studio 2309A](http://www.toshibaphotocopy.com/product/toshiba-e-studio-2309-a-photocopier/) has `Indirect Electrostatic photographic`

[Taskalfa 2200](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/products/product/taskalfa2200.technical_specification.html) has `laser mono component`

we are having a very hard time figuring out the difference in these technologies. I have search through the web but didn't find any expalnations.
`

Comment: I have to choose between these three because of our process, and the only confusion is with the printing technology.

Comment: Crossposting to [/r/Printers](https://www.reddit.com/r/printers/) may help you reach a more specialised audience. Otherwise, hopefully you'll get some more views due to the bounty, but keep in mind we're still a small community on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all various ways of referring to the same process, which a [Xerox engineer invented](https://www.xerox.com/en-us/innovation/chester-carlson-xerography) (hence the name of their company): [Xerography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerography).

HowStuffWorks has a decent overview of the process [here](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/laser-printer.htm).

So, to directly answer your question, **they all use the same printing technology**.